# movw raises undefined instruction exception on ARMv7-A

Tags: assembly, arm

I have an ARM v7a Cortex A9 processor and ran into a undefined instruction. I set a breakpoint on 0x04 to be able to look at the the register contents.
However, I dont know what is wrong with the instruction.
My R14_undef has the value 0x1003d368
and the disassembly shows:

```
1003d360:       e3a02048        mov     r2, #72 ; 0x48
1003d364:       e30e1024        movw    r1, #57380      ; 0xe024
1003d368:       e3411003        movt    r1, #4099       ; 0x1003
1003d36c:       e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
1003d370:       ebff5401        bl      1001237c <__wrap_memcpy>
```

According to websites such as [Arm Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/b/System-Level-Architecture/The-System-Level-Programmers--Model/Exceptions/Exception-entry) I have to substract -4 from the LR value to find the violating exception, i.e. 1003d364.

**But what can be wrong with `1003d364:       e30e1024        movw    r1, #57380`?**

The contents of the registers are:

```
r0             0x3  3
r1             0x1  1
r2             0x48 72
r3             0x30480000   810024960
r4             0xaaaaaaaa   2863311530
r5             0x10000000   268435456
r6             0x1807fcb8   403176632
r7             0x3  3
r8             0x18082180   403186048
r9             0x1  1
r10            0x1807fcb8   403176632
r11            0x100034c4   268448964
r12            0x1003d314   268686100
sp             0x11008000   0x11008000
lr             0x1003d368   268686184
pc             0x4  0x4
cpsr           0xa00001db   2684355035
```

Comment: Weird, GCC and clang both agree that `-mcpu=cortex-a9` should support 16-bit immediate MOVW.  https://godbolt.org/z/49fhvT3Wd

Comment: Do other similar `movw`s work without incident? Perhaps your memory or cache is corrupted (instructions overwritten without icache flush?)

Comment: The movw a few lines before worked without a problem

Comment: How can I find out if the memory/cache is corrupted?

Comment: You could try single-stepping at run-time, to make sure the code bytes in memory still disassemble to that `movw`.  (Or just hex-dump the machine-code bytes in your exception handler, for offline disassembly, if you don't have a full debugger setup.)

Comment: So far it was always the same address which I see with objdump when reading the adress-content with gdb.

Comment: Now I got some different commands at the addresses in question. How would I debug that? (I currently try to implement -fsanitize=address, but with empty implementations so far and the program crashes in a low_level_init function before main. Without -fsanitize=address that sample application works.)

Comment: what is the instruction before the mov (not movw but mov?)  address 1003d35C

Comment: @old_timer its "sub    r3, r3, #72 " before the mov

Comment: Another weird thing is, if I step by "si" (step instruction) it doesnt seem to crash, but when I use continue or "next instruction"(and thus stepping over functions in one step) it crashes in the function it doesnt crash in when using "si".

Comment: then it is probably not that instruction that is the issue.  you have something else going on